# Applying Ito's formula to a complicated expression

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I am faced with some (predictable) process $(r_t)$ and let $0 \leq t \leq T$. I am baffled with the issue of applying Ito's formula to the process
$$ \bigg\{ \int_{t}^{T} G(s-t, r_t) \,ds \bigg\}_{t \in [0,T]},$$
where $G:[0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as your process is made up of Riemann integrals and the function $G$ is smooth, I would try [differentiating under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) to get the relevant partial derivatives, which can then be plugged into Ito's lemma. So, for instance, if we label the process $X_t$, then

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}X_t&{}={}&\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\,\,\int\limits_{t}^{T}G(s-t, r_s)\ \mathrm{d}s\right)\newline
&&\newline
&{}={}&\int\limits_{t}^{T}\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}G\right)\mathrm{d}s{}-{}G(0,r_t)\,,\newline
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
... and so on.